# Packaging with CDBS: delete png file from source packages when build package (debian)

Tags: packaging, deb, cdbs

I'm trying to package a source tarball, which contains contain help/C/figures directory with 5 png files.
I want to delete 2 png files from this directory.
Putting the deletion in the clean target could be an option, but I really hate to modify my source tree that much while packaging.

If I delete this 2 files, when I run:

```
bzr builddeb -- -S -us -uc
```

This warning show up:

```
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file help/C/figures/mp3.png
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file help/C/figures/wav.png
```

These files is regenerated on build time. So I'd like to have them removed.

So no way to do it with CDBS in debian/rules?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything set up to use bzr-builddeb, so I can't test, but I would guess that it passes on extra parameters unchanged to dpkg-buildpackage. If so, you should just be able to add something like:

```
--source-option=--include-removal
```

to the `bzr builddeb` arguments. Would that solve your problem?